# angular 2 authentication with local storage

Tags: angular

> " I have two components 1.register 2.login .
>   i have a local storage which saves all the users information in the register component, i need to authenticate the registered users from the login component to the home component , i am working on angular 2 how to do it.i saved all the users to the local storage from the register component , from the login component i need to check if the users are stored in the local storage and then navigate to the home component ."

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 provides [Route Guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards)

What you want is [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard)

**routing.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'login',
  loadChildren: 'app/pages/login/login.module#LoginModule'
}, {
  path: 'authorize',
  loadChildren: 'app/pages/authorize/authorize.module#AuthorizeModule',
  canActivate: [LoginGuard]
}];
```

**login.guard.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```